# Pandas Dataframe.apply() raises typeerror for providing too many arguments

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, apply

I have this function:

```
def function(row,args):
array   = np.array(row['Revenue'+args[0]:'Revenue'+str(args[1])]).astype(float)
if np.mean(array) < (5000/12):
    return 'XXS'
if np.mean(array) < (10000/12):
    return 'XS'
if np.mean(array) < (25000/12):
    return 'S'
if np.mean(array) < (50000/12):
    return 'M'
if np.mean(array) < (250000/12):
    return 'L'
if np.mean(array) < (750000/12):
    return 'XL'
if np.mean(array) >= (750000/12):
    return 'XXL'
```

I want to apply this function using Pandas.Dataframe.apply(). So I use args, since I need to pass two additional arguments.

```
df.apply(function,axis=1,args=(VARIABLE1,VARIABLE2))
```

Somehow I get the error:

```
TypeError: ('klantschaling() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given')
```

I'm obviously giving two arguments: the dataframe row and args. So why do I get the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options. Either you can modify your function signature, or you can pass a tuple in `df.apply`.

The first option would be to redefine your function like this:

```
def function(row, arg1, arg2):
    ...
```

And then call `df.apply` as you are. The second, simpler alternative is to wrap your arguments in an iterable:

```
df.apply(function, axis=1, args=([VARIABLE1, VARIABLE2], ))
```

Or,

```
df.apply(function, axis=1, args=((VARIABLE1, VARIABLE2), ) )
```

Comment: Simply adding the brackets doesn't work yet. Something else needs to be done when I do that?

Comment: @Duudsrednaz Try `args=((VARIABLE1, VARIABLE2), )`?

Comment: @Duudsrednaz I just suppose the braces aren't recognised as tuples without the comma, to indicate you are passing a list of arguments, one of which is a tuple. Bit hard for me to explain :)